# Not overwriting configuration data with autotools

Tags: autotools

This is probably a silly question that is supposed to be well documented, but I couldn't find any intuitive or simple way to do what I need (but then, what's intuitive when the autotools are involved?).

I have a configure-based project, which also automatically installs some sample configuration files using the confdir and conf_DATA variables. My problem is that, everytime I do a make install, all the configuration files that were already there and may have been modified get overwritten. I'd like to avoid that, and copy the samples to, let's say, a conffile.cfg.new if conffile.cfg already exists. Is there any easy way to do so in the Makefile.am? I'd also be ok installing all the configuration files as, let's say, conffile.cfg.sample, and only the first time the software is installed copy each of the samples to a cfg ready to be used, rather than rely on the user to do so: either way, this requires some conditional install behaviour.

Any hint on what I should do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible by writing an [install data hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html) that does that.  However, usually this responsibility is thrust upon the package manager.  For example RPM and dpkg both handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I'll have to take a different approach then, e.g., using a separate target (like 'make config') to only install configuration files when the user asks to.